# Adding default tags via data migration

Tags: django, django-south, django-treebeard

I am using [hierarchical tags](https://tentacles666.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/django-hierarchical-tags-with-taggit-and-tree/) which work with [taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) and [treebeard](https://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard).  I am trying to get a data migration so I can define so tags that will be present in all instances of the app.

I have this method defined:

```
def define_tags(apps, schema_editor):
    HierarchicalTag = apps.get_model("aion", "HierarchicalTag")
    root = HierarchicalTag.add_root(name='root')
    root.save()
    leaf = HierarchicalTag.objects.get(pk=root.pk).add_child(name='ook')
    leaf.save()
```

which should create two tags "root" and a child "ook".  However, when I run the migration, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'HierarchicalTag' has no attribute 'add_root'
```

The method `add_root` is a class method of `MP_Node` from [treebeard](https://github.com/tabo/django-treebeard).

*How can I fix this?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** you can't use the treebeard API if you use `app.get_model` rather than importing it.

When you use

```
HierarchicalTag = apps.get_model("aion", "HierarchicalTag")
```

to get the HeirarchicalTag model rather than importing it, you actually don't get the treebeard API.  You're not getting the model as it's defined in your code, you're getting django's inferred version of the model based on your migrations.  That's why `app.get_model` will continue to work after you delete the actual code for a certain model (and *that* is why you use `app.get_model` in migrations rather than importing).

#### Solutions:

1. Write a destined-to-eventually-fail migration that just imports `HierarchicalTag`.
2. Continue to use `app.get_model` but then insert roots manually (see [the django-treebeard api](https://tabo.pe/projects/django-treebeard/) to figure out which fields need to be filled out manually).